# Return a number as a comma-delimited string

Tags: r, format, numbers, renjin

## Background

Due to a [bug in Renjin](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/338), the `format` family of functions are unavailable, but `sprintf` works.

## Code

Here is a replacement function that converts a number to a comma-delimited string:

```
commas <- function( n ) {
  s <- sprintf( "%03.0f", n %% 1000 )
  n <- n %/% 1000

  while( n > 0 ) {
    s <- concat( sprintf( "%03.0f", n %% 1000 ), ',', s )
    n <- n %/% 1000
  }

  gsub( '^0*', '', s )
}
```

## Question

While the code does the job, how can the implementation be sped up? That is, how can the code be written so as to make use of R vernacular (*without* using `format`, `formatC`, `prettyNum`, and the like) and without broken [Renjin packages](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/stringr) (i.e., no dependencies)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a number of Renjin packages are not fully implemented, so until a fix is in place, the code in the question is a decent work around:

```
commas <- function( n ) {
  s <- sprintf( "%03.0f", n %% 1000 )
  n <- n %/% 1000

  while( n > 0 ) {
    s <- concat( sprintf( "%03.0f", n %% 1000 ), ',', s )
    n <- n %/% 1000
  }

  gsub( '^0*', '', s )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a slick one-liner you can use to add thousands comma separators to the whole number digits of a number, without adding them to the decimal portion.  Using `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package, we can use this:

```
num <- "1234567890.12345"
str_replace_all(num, "[0-9](?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9])(?=\\.))", "\\0,")
[1] "1,234,567,890.12345"
```

## Demo

Comment: `str_replace_all` is also broken in Renjin. See: http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/stringr/1.2.0/build/18#test-str_replace-examples

Comment: @DaveJarvis I'm not familiar with `stringr` being broken.  My basic answer is to use a regex.  If that doesn't meet your expectations you can try something else.